# Proof Verification:Induction

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let n be a positive integer and let a1....an in the range [0,1] be real numbers. Show
$$1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}}\leq \prod_{j=1}^{n}\left (1-a_{j}\right)$$
using induction. I've shown P(1) to be true. Assume $$1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \leq \prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j)$$

LHS:
$$1 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} a_i = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i - a_{n+1} \leq \prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j) - a_{n+1}$$

Then RHS:
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{j = 1}^{n+1} (1 - a_j) &= \left(\prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j)\right)(1 - a_{n+1}) \\
&= \prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j) - \left(\prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j)\right)a_{n+1} \\
&\geq \prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j) - a_{n+1} \text{ because } (1 - a_j) \leq 1 \Rightarrow \left(\prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j)\right) \leq 1.
\end{align}$$

Anything I can improve on? Maybe make it more specific?

Comment: Your solution looks good, except for the last line where you reversed the inequality, which is probably a typo.